# WiFi says connected but isn't

Tags: wireless

I have an Acer C720 converted over to Linux (Ubuntu 14.4). The WiFi used to work but it won't work at my current hotel. It says I'm connected though. Password is correct. It just says that every page I go to is unavailable. If I boot the machine as a Chromebook then I'm fine and can access all. Similarly if I use my nexus 7 then all's OK. How can I find out what's wrong?
Mike

Comment: Please add the output of: `ps -ef | grep dhclient` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a file:

   `vi /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`
2. enter the following into that file:

   `options ath9k nohwcrypt=1`
3. `reboot`

check [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/24ippr/for_those_of_you_that_use_ath9k_and_enjoy_wifi/) out

Comment: A little explanation: passing the `nohwcrypt` parameter to the `ath9k` kernel module will cause it to use the software layer for encryption tasks, instead of relying on hardware capabilities. This assumes that the OP's problem is related to wireless encryption *(however, the Reddit link provided deals with a slightly different issue met when using both WiFi and Bluetooth)*.

Comment: @msnfreaky This assumes his Acer uses an Atheros wireless card. Are you sure it does?

Comment: The WiFi used to work under ubunto a day or two ago. It just won't work at my current hotel

Comment: @chili555 The Acer C720 comes with a AR9462 WLAN+BT chip.

Comment: I was facing the same issue as the OP and this fix solved the problem for me. On an Acer C720 running elementaryOs Luna.